# How do I add contacts to CC for a group in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I like to use the groups feature of Gmail to quickly send an email to a certain group of people that are generally always included on certain emails. For instance, I have a Family group so I can quickly email everyone in my family. This is really convenient, but it always puts all the addresses in the "To" field. I have other groups where I always want to CC certain people, while others should be in the "To" field. Is there a way to create a group in Gmail where one or more of the addresses are automatically put in the "CC" field instead of the "To" field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contacts are just addresses and groups are just collections of contacts.  Unless you write a plugin to read user defined fields from the contacts api, I don't believe that you would be able to selectively designation a contact as 'to' or 'cc'.

Otherwise, I would suggest creating two subgroups: one for the 'to's and another for the 'cc's.  Remember that contacts can be members of multiple groups.  So all of them can still be members of a 'Family' group.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to create two subgroups for a group, one with prefix *TO* and another with *CC*'s.
2. Go to *Compose mail*, in the *To* text field, write the first few letters of  your group's name (e.g. *TO AGM* or *CC GM*). As you type, you'll see the group in the list of auto-complete suggestions. Click the group to add it as a recipient of your email.
3. Follow step 2 for *CC*

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Arcege is right, create two groups one for to and one for cc and to remember add to/cc as prefix. Like as you said for family make two separate groups toFamily and ccFamily and while mailing add accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

I was looking for the answer to this which I couldn't find anywhere so will help you since I figured it out myself.

In gmail click COMPOSE
To the right in the TO column click on BCC 
another BCC field opens up, click on that to reveal SELECT CONTACTS
choose the appropriate group
SELECT ALL and then blue SELECT at the bottom.
All contacts will show up in BCC in the address bar.

Not simple but that is how it works at this time.

Comment: This isn't answering the question asked. The OP wants to know how to set up a Contact Group so that, when used, some addresses automatically go to "To:" while others automatically go to "Cc:".