# How to cc a personal contact group in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, contacts-group

I am aware of the way to send a mail to a group of users, by creating a contact list. Is there a way to add all the users to cc in a different email?

Say

```
to abc@hello.com
cc my personal group.
```

Drag and dropping of contacts doesn't seem to work.

This question is different from Web Applications questions

- *[In Gmail, how can recipients be moved back and forth between the To and CC fields?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33296)* and
- *[How do I add contacts to CC for a group in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12654)*.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Adding email addresses to CC by using a contact group is the same as adding to the TO field. Are you asking how to send individual messages to your CC list?

Comment: I do not think it is the same. See if you wish to mail all people in your contact group you can do this:

Go to Gmail -> Contacts -> Select the group -> Click on the top left most button and check the box -> All the email ids are selected. Then I can click on the mail icon and send a mail to all of them.

I wish to have the email address in my cc list and not in my to field.

Comment: If is still not clear I will post screen shots.

Comment: Ah. Simple enough. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your compose window, simply start typing the name of the contact group in the `Cc` field.

[image: compose window]

When you see the contact group you want to use, just click on it (or use the arrow keys to highlight it then press enter). All of the email addresses for the contacts in that group will be added to the field. Of course, this works for `To` and `Bcc` as well.

Comment: Excellent. There is one Glitch.
Say the group starts of with the same name as one of the memebers.e.g

Say the group name is hello
and one of the members name is hello123

When you type hello what comes up is hello123. This is what I see for larger groups (> 70). But renaming the group tp something obscure (x_a_b_c_d), solves the issue. I can live with it. Thanks for the screen shot.

Answer (score -1):

Just include all recipients in the gmail group and then simply drag and drop the cc recipient to the cc position....